# contains method not triggering on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple jeopardy game and my on.click is not triggering at all. I'm trying to have the div on click trigger only if it contains the specific text included in the variable answer.

```
    <h1 id="question">

</h1>
<div id="answer0">.</div>
<div id="answer1">.</div>
<div id="answer2">.</div>
<div id="answer3">.</div>



 var game = {
  correct: 0,

  questions: [
    "Where was bread invented?",
    "What color is the Whitehouse?",
    "Where is the Eiffel Tower?",
    "What is the capital of Texas?"
  ],
  answers: [
    ["Italy", "Japan", "Egypt", "Canada"],
    ["White", "Black", "Green", "Purple"],
    ["England", "France", "Germany", "Bulgaria"],
    ["Dallas", "Austin", "Houston", "Atlanta"]
  ],
  answer: ["Egypt", "White", "France", "Dallas"]
};
console.log(game.answer[0])


$('#question').text(game.questions[0]);
$('#answer0').text(game.answers[0][0]);
$('#answer1').text(game.answers[0][1]);
$('#answer2').text(game.answers[0][2]);
$('#answer3').text(game.answers[0][3]);

$( "#answer0" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ($('#answer0:contains(game.answer[0])').length) {
      alert("Correct!");
      game.correct++;
  }
});
$( "#answer1" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ($('#answer1:contains(game.answer[0])').length) {
      alert("Correct!");
      game.correct++;
  }
});
$( "#answer2" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ($('#answer2:contains(game.answer[0])').length) {
      alert("Correct!");
      game.correct++;
  }
});
$( "#answer3" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ($('#answer3:contains(game.answer[0])').length) {
      alert("Correct!");
      game.correct++;
  }
});
```

In this scenario it should be triggering when I click on Egypt but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two immediate problems:

```
if ($('#answer0:contains(game.answer[0])').length) {
```

Here you're looking for an element that literally contains the text `game.answer[0]`. You probably want to use the actual value of that variable, so you could do something like:

```
if ($(`#answer0:contains('${game.answer[0]}')`).length) {
```

This surrounds the string with backticks (not single quotes), so that you can interpolate variables inside of the string with `${variable}`.

Second, you always look up `answer[0]` in every `if` statement, you probably want to use the right index, for example

```
if ($(`#answer1:contains('${game.answer[1]}')`).length) {
```

You also incorrectly assumed your clicks "weren't triggering." They are triggering, but your `if` statement condition isn't being met. Adding some logging with `console.log()` can help you see what's going on in the future.

Comment: Okay, you're totally right with the first part. Howeever, the alert is still not being shown when I click on Egypt.  Your second part I don't really understand, isn't index 0 correct if i'm looking for the first item inside of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Just change code it will work fine. or use string literal

```
if ($('#answer0:contains('+game.answer[0]+')').length) {
  alert("Correct!");
  game.correct++;
}
```